# html layout with sidebar that does not overflow (no sidebars)

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to get a layout done, but it's not working its overflowing, here is a jsfiddle of what I have http://jsfiddle.net/hu3mf4Ls/ but this overflows and has other issues, what I am trying to achieve is to have the Fixed blocks and the sidebar as static as possible without scrollbars, the goal is to display this on a big screen so the goal is that there are no overflows and everything stays in place.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="background right">
    </div>
    <div class="right_block right">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

That fiddle doesn't really illustrate the issue you're having, so I'm going to guess that the right box is showing unwanted scrollbars.

If you just want to discard any extra content, and never show a scrollbar, use "overflow:hidden" in CSS.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden